# How to enter the BIOS when the fastboot mode of the motherboard is enabled?

Tags: bios, motherboard

I am using a GIGABYTE motherboard with fastboot mode enabled. In windows, I can use the software provided by GIGABYTE to enter the BIOS by just clicking a button. Can I enter the BIOS by executing a command in Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: You mean that you can enter the BIOS from the running operating system? Really? And that allows you to make changes? I assume they don't take effect until your reboot, if so. Why don't you just enter the BIOS at boot time, like one normally does?

Comment: In fastboot mode, I cannot enter the BIOS by just pressing `Delete` at boot time. I need to use a software provide by GIGABYTE to enter it. After a button click, it **reboot** into the BIOS and let me make any permanent change.

Comment: Right, so you can't actually enter it without rebooting. Why not simply disable fastboot and use the BIOS normally? All of these are Windows things though, I doubt they will be supported in Linux.

Comment: Fast boot of BIOS is  different from fast boot of windows option ...about going to BIOS setup on next boot option .. I don't think it exists in Linux.

Answer (score 6):

This in terminal worked for me just now with an Asrock A300W:

> systemctl reboot --firmware-setup

source: http://forum.asrock.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=5578